# Is there a conftest.py pytest equivalent on Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, pytest

in pytest framework conftest.py allows to setup test environment before any test execution starts. Like Reading command line arguments, setting up UUT, configure logger etc. How to do similar things in Robot Framework.

So My objective is to have a common code which will get executed before executing any of the test suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. use "suite setup" in settings table. Suite setup will execute given keyword before current test suite. More in [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown).
2. If you need to execute certain keyword before all test suites, add in a test suites directory an __init__.robot file with settings table there. Execute then whole test suites directory, not specific files. To narrow down executed test suites, use -s parameter. More info in [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files).
3. Use ROBOT_OPTIONS environmental variable - this automaticaly adds command line parameters to pybot (robot) script. For available options, look at [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#all-command-line-options). More info on init file also is in the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#robot-options-and-rebot-options-environment-variables).